# Create List<?> of a variable parameter

Tags: java, list, generics

My problem is that I'm trying to instantiate a list with a parameter that have the same class as my function's argument :

```
public <A extends CommunicationObject> List<A> Myfunction(A myObject){

    List<A> firstList;
    //do something

}
```

When I call the function :

```
List<person> persons = Myfunction(person myObject);
```

The first list take A as CommunicationObject and this is not what I want.

I also tried to do this :

```
public <A extends CommunicationObject> List<A> Myfunction(A myObject){

  List<myObject.getClass()> firstList;
    //do something
}
```

but it is not allowed. Is there any chance that I can fix this ?

Update :

"person" is a subClass of "CumminicationObject". There is some attributes that exists in person and not in CommunicationObject. Actually this is just an example. What I'm trying to do is to convert a JSON to List"<"A">", and A can be "person" or other class that extends CommunicationObject.

The JSON contain the same attributes as the "A" class in List"<"A">".

In order to do the convertion, the parameter "A" in List"<"A">" have to be the same as my object Class in myfunction(A myObject).

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Is `person` a subtype of `CommunicationObject`? If no: why are you passing it to `MyFunction`? If yes: isn't the actual behavior identical to what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java uses [type-erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which means your method declaration is somewhat pointless because there's no return type for the compiler to infer the type of `A` from.

This means that at runtime you've effectively got:

```
public void Myfunction(CommunicationObject myObject)
```

This method signature, when you think about it, is what its implementation would have to work with anyway and so your list should be a `List<CommunicationObject>`.

**Following update to the question regarding de-serialization from JSON:**

When de-serializing from JSON to a Java object you've got two choices:

- declare the type to de-serialize into at the point of de-serialization like [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples) does.
- infer the type to de-serialize into within the JSON.

Due Java's [type-erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) this is the only way to do this.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Due to the same type erasure, `firstList` is identical to `List<Object>` at runtime. But generics are there for compile-time safety. Of course, you cannot use any properties of `A` that are not defined by `CommunicationObject`, because the compiler cannot know them, but that does not mean that `A` is irrelevant. For instance, you can't do `firstList.Add(new CommunicationObject())`.

Comment: The list is largely irrelevant to be honest.  The point is, including the generic is pointless because the compiler will complain if you wrote `MyFunction("break")` whether the method is declared with  generics (as in the question) or without generics (as in the answer).  And so using generics achieves nothing

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I resolved the problem with a similar way. It's to complicated to be exposed here. But your answer can inspire any one who got the same problem